# Performing clustering on a text column in a data frame

Tags: r, nlp, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe (df) which has two column called "id" and "text"

```
id  text
1   TV
2   Tv
3   T.V
4   Radio/TV
5   Car
6   CAR
7   car
```

I want to tag/flag the similar types of rows in the "text" column

Expected Output:

```
id  text     type
1   TV       tv
2   Tv       tv
3   T.V      tv
4   Radio/TV tv
5   Car      car
6   CAR      car
7   car      car
```

I found the following while researching, I get the logic here and it executes too, but I can't figure out how I can recreate what I have in my mind (expected output)

```
# Importing the library
library(tm)

# Importing the data
corpus.tmp<-Corpus(VectorSource(df$text))

#Cleaning up
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp,removePunctuation)
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripWhitespace)
corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

# Document Matrix
TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus.tmp)
inspect(TDM)

tdm_tfxidf<-weightTfIdf(TDM)

# Converting to matrix
m<- as.matrix(tdm_tfxidf)
rownames(m)<- 1:nrow(m)

norm_eucl<- function(m)
  m/apply(m,1,function(x) sum(x^2)^.5)

m_norm<-norm_eucl(m)

# Performing K means clustering
results<-kmeans(m_norm,5,5)
```

Comment: Can the text column contain a string such as `cartv`? If not, you could strip the text column from all characters but `acrtv`

Comment: No, but there can be multiple variation, and the list can keep growing! clustering made a lot of sense to me here

Comment: k-means does *not* expect a distance matrix. And no, this approach will not work. You need a language model, not a least-variance approach like k-means (which is built for continuous, numerical data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text column *either* contains a string with `car` or `tv` in any fasion with special characters, you could remove the special characters and check if the string contains `tv` or `car`:

```
## Your dataframe
df <- data.frame(id = seq(7), text = c("tv","TV","T.v","Radio/TV","Car","car","CAR"))

## Remove special characters
df$text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df$text)

## Logicals for which df$text contain "tv" or "car"
tv <- grepl("tv",df$text,ignore.case = TRUE)
car <- grepl("car",df$text,ignore.case = TRUE)

## Create df$type column and assign values
df$type[tv] <- "tv"
df$type[car] <- "car"
```

If you have many more names to check for, you could collect the last two steps into an `sapply`, however this approach is not failproof - e.g. if text contains something like `cartv`.

Comment: I see that your approach will work for before defined cases, but I am looking for something that does not require maintenance per say. But thanks for the answer